# How To Add Row Dynamic with Rowspan in Table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, html-table

I have 2 add button. First add button on header, click this button will add 1 new row. Second add button in table (such as image on my post), click this button will add new row such as image my post. I want add row in table such as below image, but i haven't thought of a solution yet. Hope to be got your helps!

[View Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dySTm.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The `insertRow()` method allows you to add rows to a `<table>` and returns a reference to a new row. Adding that to an `onClick()` function should be easy! :)

Here's the relevant information on [Mozilla's site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow) .

Comment: Thanks you so much! But, your link haven't solved my problem yet. :( :( I have 2 add button. First add button on header, click this button will add 1 new row. Second add button in table (such as image on my post), click this button will add new row such as image my post.

Comment: I believe you'll just need to do the same thing again.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you have to add a new table inside td, like this

```js
function addNewRow() {
    let table = document.getElementById("add");
    table.innerHTML  += '<table><tr><td><b>This is a test</b></td></tr></table>';
}
```

```html
  <html>
      <body>
          <button onclick="addNewRow()">Add</button>
          <table id='my-table'>
              <tr>
                  <td>This is one td</td>
                  <td id='add'>This is another td</td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! Your link haven't solved my problem yet. I have 2 add button. First add button on header, click this button will add 1 new row. Second add button in table (such as image on my post), click this button will add new row such as image my post.

Comment: @TrinhThienAn please, try the snippet